# Deserializing json in Angular 2/4 using HttpClientModule

Tags: json, angular, rest, typescript

So I'm getting the following JSON structure from my `asp.net core` api:

```
{
  "contentType": null,
  "serializerSettings": null,
  "statusCode": null,
  "value": {
     "productName": "Test",
     "shortDescription": "Test 123",
     "imageUri": "https://bla.com/bla",
     "productCode": null,
     "continuationToken": null
  }
}
```

I have the following typescript function that invokes the API to get the above response:

```
public externalProduct: ProductVM;


getProductExternal(code: string): Observable<ProductVM> {
    return this.http.get("api/product?productCode=" + code)
        .map((data: ProductVM) => {
            this.externalProduct = data; //not working...
            console.log("DATA: " + data);
            console.log("DATA: " + data['value']);
            return data;
        });    
}
```

ProductVM:

```
export interface ProductVM {

    productName: string;
    shortDescription: string;
    imageUri: string;
    productCode: string;
    continuationToken: string;
}
```

My problem is that I can't deserialize it to `ProductVM`. The console logs just produce `[object Object]`

How can I actually map the contents of the `value` in my json response to a `ProductVM` object?

Is it wrong to say that `data` is a `ProductVM` in the map function? I have tried lots of different combinations but I cannot get it to work!

I'm unsure whether I can somehow automatically tell `angular` to map the value array in the `json` response to a `ProductVM` object or if I should provide a constructor to the `ProductVM` class (it's an interface right now), and extract the specific values in the `json` manually?

Comment: What is the type that your API is returning? Do you also return a similar ProductVM? Looks like you have some sort of wrapper on your API return. The actual data you want is on the value property. Also, why you want to map on the result? http get returns an Observable.. so you can just subscribe to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `data` object in the map method chained to http is considered a `Object` typed object. This type does not have the `value` member that you need to access and therefore, the type checker is not happy with it.

Objects that are typed (that are not `any`) can only be assigned to untyped objects or objects of the exact same type. Here, your data is of type `Object` and cannot be assigned to another object of type `ProductVM`.

One solution to bypass type checking is to cast your data object to a `any` untyped object. This will allow access to any method or member just like plain old Javascript.

```
getProductExternal(code: string): Observable<ProductVM> {
  return this.http.get("api/product?productCode=" + code)
    .map((data: any) => this.externalProduct = data.value);    
}
```

Another solution is to change your API so that data can deliver its content with `data.json()`. That way, you won't have to bypass type checking since the json() method returns an untyped value.

Be carefull though as your `any` object wil not have methods of the `ProductVM` if you ever add them in the future. You will need to manually create an instance with `new ProductVM()` and `Object.assign` on it to gain access to the methods.

Comment: `.map(data => Object.assign(new ProductVM(), data))`should work too.

Comment: Be very careful with nested objects though as they will not be typed unless instanciated manually.

Comment: Hmm, just as in srAxi's answer. I cannot seem to call anything on data. If I write data.value I get "property 'value' does not exist on type 'Object'. Any idea why I'm getting this compile error? Also if I say data.json() it will also complain. Hovering over data shows me that it is of type 'Object'.

Comment: Did you try with just data? Not data.value

Comment: and what about declaring data like so: `.map((data: any) => ...`?

Comment: You could also try a debug session with data typed to `any` to see what does `data`, `data.json()`, `data.value` and `data.json().value` return.

Comment: It works thank you. The data:any did the trick. But I'm confused as to why I need to use Object.Assign. If I remove it so it's just this.externalProduct = data.value it will not work, only works with your Object.Assign solution.

Comment: The typing is gone after the compilation. Typescript typing is only a constraint pre-compilation. If your compiler think data is a given type, it will not allow you to compile if you call a method or property it doesn't know to be present on this type. I have little info about the `Object` type, but I suspect it doesn't have a `value` property.

Comment: This one liner should work then: `.map((data: any) => Object.assign(new ProductVM(), data.value))` right?

Comment: What's the error you get when you directly assign without Object.assign?

Comment: Yes it does! well I need to store it in the externalProduct variable so this works: `map((data: any) => Object.assign(this.externalProduct, data.value))`

Comment: Huh. Now this also works!: `map((data: any) => this.externalProduct = data.value)`

Comment: Yeah ok I get it. The thing is you can assign an `any` type to anything but this is not true for an `Object` type. And because you have to access the value property, you can't keep the Object type and need to cast to `any`

Comment: Be careful though, if you assign directly the `any` typed object, you won't have access to the potential methods of the `ProductVM` type at runtime (if you ever add some).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm just getting started with angular so this is still a bit confusing but I learnt so much just by asking this question here.

Comment: The HTTP deserialization is a mess in Angular, I've had a lot of trouble with it. But it helps to understand how typing actually work in angular to sort things out.

Answer (score 2):

[From angular documentation: Typechecking http response](https://angular.io/guide/http#typechecking-the-response)

You have to set the type of returned data when using new httpClient ( since angular 4.3 ) => this.http.get<**ProductVM**>(...

```
public externalProduct: ProductVM;    
getProductExternal(code: string): Observable<ProductVM> {
        return this.http.get<ProductVM>("api/product?productCode=" + code)
            .map((data: ProductVM) => {
                this.externalProduct = data; // should be allowed by typescript now
                return data;
            });    
    }
```

thus typescript should leave you in peace

Answer (score 1):

```
getProductExternal(code: string): Observable<ProductVM> {
    return this.http.get("api/product?productCode=" + code)
        .map(data => {
            this.externalProduct = <ProductVM>data;
            console.log("DATA: " + this.externalProduct);
            return data;
        });    
}
```

So, first we convert the response into a JSON.
I store it into `response` just to make it cleaner. Then, we have to navigate to `value`, because in your data `value` is the object that corresponds to `ProductVM`.

I would do it like this though:

**Service**

```
getProductExternal(code: string): Observable<ProductVM> {
        return this.http.get(`api/product?productCode=${code}`)
            .map(data => <ProductVM>data)
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));    
    }
```

**Component**

```
this.subscription = this.myService.getProductExternal(code).subscribe(
  product => this.externalProduct = product,
  error => console.warn(error)
);
```

Comment: Oh. So you're not restricting data to be of any type. That makes totally sense, why would it be a ProductVM at that point. So this line "this.externalProduct = <ProductVM>response.value" will do the actual deserialization to ProductVM object? I'll try this and get back to you!

Comment: @DSF If you feel like, try the 2nd approach. I believe is cleaner. I hope it helps. ;)

Comment: I'm getting a compile error when using json(). "Property json does not exist on type Object". I'm using: import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

Comment: Remove json(). My bad. HttpClient already applies json() to responses...

Comment: Then I'm just getting "Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Object'. Hovering over data tells me that it's of type 'Object', but value doesn't exist on Object, how do I get past this error?

Comment: If the response is as you posted, you need to navigate through it. Remove `.value` an see if it gets the data. The thing is that in the response you posted the data was inside the `value` property, that's why I did `data.value`.  So, at this stage, with `data => <ProductVM>data` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to replace

```
this.externalProduct = data;
```

with

```
this.externalProduct = data.json();
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I used this approach in a client which uses the method

```
HttpClient.get<GENERIC>(...).
```

Now it is working. Anyway, I do not understand, why I do not receive a type of T back from the http client, if I don't use the solution provided in the answer above.

Here is the client:

```
// get
get<T>(url: string, params?: [{key: string, value: string}]): Observable<T> {
var requestParams = new HttpParams()

if (params != undefined) {
  for (var kvp of params) {
    params.push(kvp);
  }
}

return this.httpClient.get<T>(url, {
  observe: 'body',
  headers: this.authHeaders,
  params: requestParams
}).pipe(
  map(
    res => <T>res
  )
);
}
```